# Issue with getJson in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net mvc 4 project where in client side I need to send part data via ajax and then display returned result. But all what I have in response is []. I'm debugging and I'm sure that have not null List<> collection. Does anybody know where is my mistake?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            $('#navigation a').click(function () {
                $.getJSON('/Home/GetJobList', function (data) {
                    $("#headerJobRow").text("");
                    $.each(data, function (i, job) {
                        $("#headerJobRow").append("<li>" + job.Title + "</li>");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetJobList()
        {
            int roll = 0;
            if (Request.Cookies["CityId"] != null) {
                roll = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["CityId"].Value);
            }
            IQueryable<JobsDb_JobPostings> jobs = roll > 1 ? _jobPostRepo.GetAll().Where(x => x.CityID == roll).OrderByDescending(x => x.PostingID) : _jobPostRepo.GetAll().OrderByDescending(x => x.PostingID);

            return Json(jobs.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are u nesting `ready` handler

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Is equivalent to

```
$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$.getJSON is an asynchronous function, therefore your code immediately following will execute before the server side action has returned.

You need to wait for the .done() callback and access data in that.

```
$.getJSON('/Home/GetJobList', function (data) {
}).done(function(data){
   $("#headerJobRow").text("");
      $.each(data, function (i, job) {
          $("#headerJobRow").append("<li>" + job.Title + "</li>");
      });

};
```

EDIT: Sorry you need to pass the *data* parameter to the .done callback.  Updated the code to show that.

Comment: The same return value equals []

Comment: The function he specified in the $.getJSON() method gets called when the request is returned successfully, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Ah yes you're correct.  I've always preferred to use the .done() callback.